# Issue accessing Startup Security Utility on brand new Macbook Pro M1

Tags: security, recovery, apple-silicon, driver

I'm trying to follow [this](https://motu.com/techsupport/technotes/apple-silicon-motu-audio-inst) guide to install a driver for my audio interface on a brand new Macbook Pro M1 16".

I'm booting into recovery mode, but when I click into "Utilities", I'm prompted with the message "*There are no users on this volume to recover*" and two options to Restart.

The Macbook works perfectly well in all other areas when booted normally. I just need to change the security policy to allow this driver to work, but I can't get through. Very frustrating -- any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay after some more troubleshooting and searching - I enabled FileVault encryption, and that worked????!

Just posting for posterity if any1 has a similar issue :)

Comment: You should probably accept your own answer, then